# Cli download ftp directory multithread

Tags: command-line, server, cron, ftp

I am renting a sharing hosting server with 30 websites on it and one ubuntu server at my home. I want to take a backup from the sharing server to my home server.

I made a cron job with wget command but finally it takes two days to download all ftp files one by one. I realised that I need a command for multithread download.

With more search I try with aria2 but aria2 download single files and needs url list file to download all my websites.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way to generate with a cli an url_list_file.txt?
2. Is there another 'multithreading' way to download an ftp directory?

Comment: Are there any other connection methods you may use to connect to your shared hosting? Some providers allow ssh for example.